# How to design three dimension nosql database using Firebase

Tags: firebase, database-design, data-modeling, database, nosql

I am using Firebase as database for an e-commerce app.
I got a problem in the product catalog design.

My idea is:
1. One product can have different sizes. (e.g. S, M, L, XL)
2. One product can also have different colors. (e.g. black, blue, bronze, red)
3. The price can vary depends on different size **OR** different color, e.g. a medium size T-shirt in black is $100, while the same size T-shirt but in blue is $150.
In other words, there can be up to 9 different prices for one T-shirt which has 3 sizes and 3 colors.

Below is the design I can come up with.
I stored the sizes, colors, and the prices in the child 'sku'.
Under this child, I put the price for different color in the child 'price'
But I think it is not the best design so hope anyone could advise a better solution.

For security reason, I have hidden part of the unique key.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remodel your database according to your needs.

```
Products
    |
    -Kj53453453453453 //ProductId
    |   |
        --- Small_Size: true
    |   |
        --- Black_Color: true
    |   |
        --- Quantity: 7
    |   |
        --- Price: 100
    |   |
        --- ProductId: T_SHORT_ID // which must be the same for all t-shirts of same type
    |
    -Kj53453794677886 //ProductId
        |
        --- XL_Size: true
        |
        --- Red_Color: true
        |
        --- Quantity: 9
        |
        --- Price: 65
        |
        --- ProductId: T_SHORT_ID // which must be the same for all t-shirts of same type

Sizes
    |
    --- Small_Size: "S"
    |
    --- Medium_Size: "M"
    |
    --- Large_Size: "L"
    |
    --- XL_Size: "XL"
    |
    --- XXL_Size: "XXL"
Colors
    |
    --- Black_Color: "Black"
    |
    --- Blue_Color: "Blue"
    |
    --- Bronze_Color: "Bronze"
    |
    --- Red_Color: "Red"
```

Using this model you'll be able to have a node for each product separately. This means, let say for the first product which has the `-Kj53453453453453` as an id, you know that is back and the size si S. For this type of product you know also that you have 7 pieces. When someone is buying a piece, the only thing you need to do, is to decrease the quantity by one, that's it!

Creating the correct queries, you'll be able to display everything from your database, all products, all sizes, all colors, all products that are black, all products that have the size of XL and so on.

Hope iti helps.

Comment: I mean, the same product, has different sizes and different colors, and the price may vary depends on these two conditions.

Comment: No, your approach is wrong. Let's take an example. Let's assume we have 100 t-shorts, with different colors, diferrent sizes. If someone is buying a t-short, black color and size XL, how do know how many products are remaining. It's simple, 100-1=99. But how can i know how many product are remaining of the same color and same size? How many products are remaining other colors ans other sizes? So in order to know every detail of every item in your database you need to `flatten` your data as mentioned above.

Comment: Take your first product ID as example, -Kj53453453453453 //ProductId has two size, small and large, two color, black and white. Here are the four situations: 1. Small black T-shirt is selling at $100. 2. Small white T-shirt is selling at $120. 3. Large black T-shirt is selling at $150. 4. Large white T-shirt is selling at $170. They should use the same product Id but just vary in color and size, how we display this relationship?

Comment: That's no problem at all, you add a new field, name `productId` and set the same product id for each product but be carefull is not the pushed id generated by the push method, and that's it.

Comment: I edited your answer, so your approach is like this? To treat every combination as a new record while keeping the same product Id as one of its field?

Comment: I edited again because the product id must be the product id from your papers, not the unique generated id by the `push()` method. Yes, this is what i mean because in this way you can query your database in every way you like, and you'll have all the answers.

Comment: The app flow is when the user clicks the 'buy' button，all the sizes should pop up，e.g. S，M，L，after the user clicks one of the sizes，all the colors will pop up，e.g. red，black，yellow，my concern is，this structure is not easy to do that？As the key for size and color vary and not easy to iterate.

Comment: Yes, it's fine your app flow. In this database structure, it's very easy to pop-up all colors and all sizes because you only need to put a `listener` on `Colors` and `Sizes` nodes. In this way, every time a user clicks a color and a size, you'll know what kind of product is. In this way you'll know for sure from which product to decrease the quantity.

Comment: Hi Alex， I am going to design my variant following below tutorial，the variant data model, it is different from your answer however I will check your answer: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/retail-reference-architecture-part-1-building-flexible-searchable-low-latency-product